# Spannable text in TextView not showing properly

Tags: android, textview, spannable

I had this code working fine, but when updating the build tools and libraries from 26.0.2 to 27.0.3, the TextViews started to cut the text. There are 4 TextViews in a LinearLayout. Each TextView has a width 0dp and a weight of 1. All TextViews have a 4 letters word so they are supposed to show identically, however that build tools update ruined it.

```
        String s = "ssss";
        float textBigger = 1.5f;
        SpannableString ss1 = new SpannableString(s);
        int index = 2;
        ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(textBigger), 0, index, 0); // set size
        ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(biggerTextColor), 0, index, 0);// set color
        textView.setText(ss1, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

How it is supposed to look:
[image]

How it is now looking:
[image]

Libraries updated from 26.0.2:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
```

EDIT:

After more debugging, I changed back my gradle to have the following:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
targetSdkVersion 23
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
```

Now by just changing targetSdkVersion to 27, the problem arises. The spannable thing has nothing to do with it. The text in the TextViews is behaving differently. It is even showing in the AndroidStudio xml preview that the text is cut when the targetSdkVersion is set to 27.

To test it out, create a project with the gradle settings above. And the below MainActivity layout. Change targetSdkVersion from 23 to 27 and you should see the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ziadalhalabi.testspannable.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Amin"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Bmin"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Cmaj"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Dmin"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Gmaj"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="C#min"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="F#min"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does "cut the text" mean? What does "ruined it" mean? What is the value of `textBigger`? What is the value of `biggerTextColor`? What is the difference between the four `TextView` widgets? Do you have a screenshot of what you are expecting, compared with what you are seeing?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your comment. I uploaded 2 screenshots and added more infos

Comment: OK... that's pretty strange. I have difficulty believing that `buildToolsVersion` would have an effect like this. I can easily see having problems based on other changes (e.g., you use `appcompat-v7` and upgraded to some newer version of that). If you create a project that reproduces the effect, and upload that somewhere, I'd be interested in taking a look to see if I can get it to happen here.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am sorry the libraries were updated according to the build tool version too

Comment: Ah, that's a more likely source of your difficulty. The `buildToolsVersion` and the library versions are largely independent. The library versions tie into your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. Try sticking with `buildToolsVesrion '27.0.3'`, but dropping `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `26`, and dropping the support libraries version to `26.1.0`. If the problem goes away, my guess is that the issue is tied to `appcompat-v7:27.0.2`, and if you file a bug report with a project that reproduces the problem, they should be able to fix it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did what you suggested and the problem remained. So I did further debugging, please check my new edit in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was able to reproduce the problem. It's entirely possible that there is an underlying bug in `appcompat-v7` here. However, you can fix this by simplifying your layout. Replace the combination of `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` with a simple `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` on all your `TextView` widgets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">


  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:text="Amin"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:text="Bmin"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:text="Cmaj"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:text="Dmin"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

  </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">


    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:text="Gmaj"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:text="C#min"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:text="F#min"
      android:textSize="18sp" />


  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

That, with `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` both set to 27, and using `27.0.2` of `appcompat-v7`, gives you this on a Nexus 5X running Android 8.1:

[image: Results of layout]

With your original approach, what seemed to be happening was that Android was trying to word-wrap those lines, but since you had `maxLines` set to `1`, it wound up truncating those lines instead.